How to send a PDF attachment via SOAP API in .NET Framework 4.8 / .NET Core using HttpClient?
I'm working with a SOAP API that accepts a PDF document as an attachment. I'm developing a .NET Framework 4.8 console application, and I need to send a PDF file along with other information in the SOAP request.
Here is the code I have tried:
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string serviceUrl = "soapapiurl"; // Replace with your SOAP API endpoint
        string boundary = "----=_Part_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Read the attachment file
        string filePath = @"D:\C#Projects\CarFinanceFiles\NETRoadmap.pdf";
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        string fileContentId = "NETRoadmap.pdf";

        // Construct the SOAP envelope
        string soapEnvelope = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:vo=""http://vo.service.ws.proposal.wcg.com"">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <vo:SendDocumentRequest>
      <vo:documentUploader>
        <vo:fileType>PAY</vo:fileType>
        <vo:documentName>NETRoadmap</vo:documentName>
        <vo:documentData>cid:" + fileContentId + @"</vo:documentData>
      </vo:documentUploader>
    </vo:SendDocumentRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

        // Create the multipart content
        var multipartContent = new MultipartContent("related", boundary);

        // Add the SOAP envelope part
        var soapContent = new StringContent(soapEnvelope, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
        // Important: Set Content-ID for the SOAP part if needed
        soapContent.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("type", "\"application/soap+xml\""));
        multipartContent.Add(soapContent);

        // Add the attachment part
        var attachmentContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
        attachmentContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        attachmentContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath),
            // The Content-ID should match the cid used in the SOAP envelope
            Name = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
        };
        attachmentContent.Headers.Add("Content-ID", $"<{fileContentId}>");
        multipartContent.Add(attachmentContent);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Set headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "SendDocument");

            // Send the request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, multipartContent);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Response received:");
                Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {response.StatusCode}");
                string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(errorContent);
            }
        }
    }
}

But I am getting this error:

500 - <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap:Bodysoap:Faultsoap:ClientUnmarshalling Error: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'cid:NETRoadmap.pdf' is not a valid value for 'base64Binary'. </soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

But it worked via SOAP UI by enabling MTOM to true. Kindly help me

Looking at your error message:
'cid:NETRoadmap.pdf' is not a valid value for 'base64Binary'
This suggests that the SOAP API is expecting a binary representation of the PDF in this field. In other words, the actual PDF binary data itself, encoded as Base64. However, you are sending the API just the filename NETRoadmap.pdf rather than the binary content.
To fix it, try Base64 encoding your fileBytes byte array and then include it in the soapEnvelope like this:
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
string pdfAsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

// Construct the SOAP envelope
string soapEnvelope = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:vo=""http://vo.service.ws.proposal.wcg.com"">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <vo:SendDocumentRequest>
      <vo:documentUploader>
        <vo:fileType>PAY</vo:fileType>
        <vo:documentName>NETRoadmap</vo:documentName>
        <vo:documentData>cid:" + pdfAsBase64 + @"</vo:documentData>
      </vo:documentUploader>
    </vo:SendDocumentRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

You haven't given any more details about the SOAP API, but I also suspect that you don't need the attachmentContent at all. My guess is based on your error code, because it wouldn't make sense to provide the PDF content in two different ways (i.e. Base64 in the soapContent and again as the attachmentContent).
See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-8.0

I have tried that scenario also. <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap:Bodysoap:Faultsoap:ServerThe given SOAPAction SendDocument does not match an operation.</soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

The surprise is it worked in SoapUI. In soapUI, with the same requestbody and enalbed 'MTOM' tot true and added attachment with the same name...it worked

That's very odd, because your error message is really clear about this: 'cid:NETRoadmap.pdf' is not a valid value for 'base64Binary' Looking at your example, the only place that mentions cid: is the DocumentData. And it clearly says this must be a Base64 encoded string, whereas you are sending the ASCII filename instead. It does seem rather clear about that. Unless there's another place in the SOAP envelope where you're inserting cid:NetRoadmap.PDF ?
